# Definition of asymptotically flat spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature, asymptotics

Following the definition in Wald's book on general relativity, in page 276 asymptotically flat spacetimes are defined using conformal isometry with conformal factor $Ω$.

Then one of the requirements is that $Ω$ will be 0 on the boundary.

Isn't it unnecessary requirement that follows from the uncompactness of the original spacetime and the requirement that new metric will be smooth?